# Script to transfer files from one server to an archive server

Tags: scripting

I have been tasked with writing a script to transfer log files from one server to an archive server, but when I run the script I constantly get the following errors:

```
test.sh: line 4: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

test.sh: line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Script is below.

```
for D in `find  /var/log/syslog/hosts/* -type d -iname *rrp0* -o prp01* *`
do

    for F in `find $D -type f -mtime +7 -name "*.tar.gz"`
    do
            echo $F
            filename=$(basename "$F");
            SERVER=${filename%.*};
            SERVER=$(echo $SERVER |cut -d "-" -f5);
    echo $SERVER
            if [ ! -d /var/log/syslog/archive/$SERVER ]
            then
                   mkdir /var/log/syslog/archive/$SERVER;
            fi
            mv $F /var/log/syslog/archive/$SERVER
            Log is already compressed, so no need to zip/rm it
            cd $D;
            zip /var/log/syslog/archive/$SERVER/$filename.zip $filename;
            Remove original file
            yes|rm $F
    done
done
```

Comment: Assuming the "for D in .." line is part of the script:

You would either need a newline or a semi colon before the do in the end.
Also, are you sure prp01* * is matching what you intended?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first line

From

```
for D in `find  /var/log/syslog/hosts/* -type d -iname *rrp0* -o prp01* *`
```

To

```
for D in `find  /var/log/syslog/hosts/* -type d \( -iname '*rrp0*' -o -iname 'prp01*' \)`
```